# is it possible to achieve authenticated key agreement without using PKI or pre-shared secret?

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman, key-exchange, authenticated-encryption, certificates

After reading different techniques to achieve authenticated key-agreement ([X3DH](https://www.signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/x3dh.pdf), [HMQV](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/176.pdf), [Asynchronous Ratcheting tree](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/666.pdf),  [An efficient protocol for authenticated key agreement](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/1998/corr98-05.pdf), I understood that all these approaches enforce *implicit authentication* --Alice is sure that only a specifically identified Bob can derive the same key -- *explicit authentication* is enforced by they use of a trusted server or digital certificates, which are parts of Public key infrastructures (PKIs).
As an alternative to PKIs, I learned that PAKE (password-authenticated key exchange) can be used. However, those schemes usually assume parties involved in the key-agreement already have a pre-shared password, or one party has the password and the other has enough information to recognize the password [[Do all pake assume that all parties already have a password?]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81041/do-all-pake-assume-that-all-parties-already-have-a-password) 
However, I want to achieve a key-agreement without relying on PKIs or pre-shared secrets.
**Hence is there a way to perform a key-agreement resistant to a man in the middle attack without the use of PKIs or pre-shared secret?**

Comment: Face-to-face or tell your public keys by phone. Also [Station-To-Station protocol](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/64043/18298)

Comment: exactly.  Examples of "face-to-face" or equivalent are (a) bluetooth pairing -- both devices show you a 6-digit number, which you visually verify are the same and hit "pair" or "accept" on both devices, (b) Signal messenger -- visual readout and check with your correspondent that he/she has the same value.